# Simple Playlist Editor/Player

Tags: java, beginner

I am starting with Java and at the beginning I would like someone to catch what mistakes I make. I would like my code to look its best and I want to learn good Java writing habits. Could anyone explain to me where I am making mistakes or what I should do differently for this purpose?

My program presents a music playlist. To add song to a playlist, we must first add the song to the album. All 3 classes are in separate files in my program. I set up getters and setters only when I use them - I don't know if it's a good habit. calledNext flag checks whether iterator.next() was called in the previous run.

````
public class Main {

    private static LinkedList<Song> playlist = new LinkedList<>();
    private static LinkedList<Album> albums = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Album a1 = new Album();
        a1.addToAlbum("song1", 1.57);
        a1.addToAlbum("song2", 2.00);
        albums.add(a1);

        albums.get(0).addToPlaylist(playlist, "song1");
        albums.get(0).addToPlaylist(playlist, "song2");

        System.out.println();
        runPlaylist();
    }

    public static void runPlaylist() {

        ListIterator<Song> iterator = playlist.listIterator();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean quit = false;
        boolean calledNext = true;

        System.out.println("Now playing " + iterator.next().toString());
        printMenu();

        while (!quit) {

            if (playlist.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Playlist is empty");
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Enter your choice ");
            int x = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();

            switch (x) {
                case 1:
                    quit = true;
                    System.out.println("bye bye");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (!calledNext)
                        if (iterator.hasNext())
                            iterator.next();

                    calledNext = true;

                    if (iterator.hasNext())
                        System.out.println("Now playing: " + iterator.next().toString());
                    else
                        System.out.println("No more songs in the playlist");

                    break;

                case 3:
                    if (calledNext)
                        if (iterator.hasPrevious())
                            iterator.previous();

                    calledNext = false;

                    if (iterator.hasPrevious())
                        System.out.println("Now playing: " + iterator.previous().toString());
                    else
                        System.out.println("You are at the beginning");

                    break;

                case 4:
                    if (calledNext) {
                        if (iterator.hasPrevious())
                            System.out.println("Replaying: " + iterator.previous().toString());
                        else
                            System.out.println("Replaying: " + playlist.getFirst().toString());

                        calledNext = false;
                    } else {
                        if (iterator.hasNext())
                            System.out.println("Replaying: " + iterator.next().toString());
                        else
                            System.out.println("Replaying: " + playlist.getLast().toString());

                        calledNext = true;
                    }

                    break;

                case 5:
                    printMenu();
                    break;

                case 6:
                    String titleToAdd = scanner.nextLine();

                    for (int i = 0; i < albums.size(); i++) {
                        Album currentAlbum = albums.get(i);
                        if (!currentAlbum.addToPlaylist(playlist, titleToAdd))
                            System.out.println("Song not found in album");
                    }
                    break;

                case 7:
                    String titleToRemove = scanner.nextLine();

                    for (int i = 0; i < albums.size(); i++) {
                        Album currentAlbum = albums.get(i);
                        if (!currentAlbum.removeFromPlaylist(playlist, titleToRemove))
                            System.out.println("Song not found in playlist");
                    }
                    if (!playlist.isEmpty())
                        System.out.println("Now playing: " + playlist.getFirst().toString());
                    break;

                case 8:
                    System.out.println(playlist);
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("Instructions : \nPress" +
                " 1 to exit\n" +
                "2 to play next song\n" +
                "3 to play previous song\n" +
                "4 replay\n" +
                "5 print menu \n" +
                "6 add song to playlist\n" +
                "7 remove song from playlist\n" +
                "8 print playlist\n");
    }

public class Album {

    private ArrayList<Song> songs;

    public Album() {
        this.songs = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void addToAlbum(String title, double duration) {
        if (checkAlbum(title) == null) {
            songs.add(new Song(title, duration));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Song already in album");
        }
    }

    public void removeFromAlbum(String title) {
        Iterator<Song> iterator = songs.iterator();
        if (checkAlbum(title) != null) {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                if (iterator.next().getTitle().equals(title)) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean addToPlaylist(LinkedList<Song> playlist, String title) {
        Song checkedSong = checkAlbum(title);
        if (checkedSong != null) {
            playlist.add(checkedSong);
            System.out.println("Song " + title + " has been added to playlist");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean removeFromPlaylist(LinkedList<Song> playlist, String title) {

        for (int i = 0; i < playlist.size(); i++) {
            Song currentSong = playlist.get(i);
            if (currentSong.getTitle().equals(title)) {
                playlist.remove(currentSong);
                System.out.println("Song " + title + " has been removed from playlist");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Song checkAlbum(String title) {
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
            Song currentSong = songs.get(i);
            if (currentSong.getTitle().equals(title)) {
                return currentSong;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class Song {

    private String title;
    private double duration;

    public Song(String title, double duration) {
        this.title = title;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.title + ": " + this.duration;
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest avoiding `static` state. It makes your code more rigid. It works for this very simple app, but the limitations become more apparent in more complex apps. You should remove the `static` keywords from your two lists and the `runPlaylist` method. You can instantiate an instance of the class to use in `main()` and call public methods on it.

Some of your functionality doesn't employ separation of concerns. For example, your `Album` class has an `addToPlaylist` method. The functionality of the method is to check if the given `Song` is a member of the `Album` and only add it to the provided list if it is. The only part of that having anything to do with the `Album` is seeing if it owns the `Song`. Having the `Album` responsible for all that other behavior is tangling up your classes. On a large-scale, complicated project, this kind of code would become very difficult to maintain.

So, I would remove `addToPlaylist` and `removeFromPlaylist` from the `Album` class. I would change the method `checkAlbum` to `containsSong` (names are important for code legibility!) and return a `boolean`. Those two removed methods should be moved up to the `Main` class, since it is the owner of the `Album` and the `Playlist` and so it is the one that knows what it wants to do with a Song.

You are currently comparing `Song`s by their `title` field. This requires other classes (in this case `Album`) to dig into its internals to be able to compare `Song`s. Instead, you should have `Album` override `equals()` and provide the behavior you want. Since you are currently ignoring the `duration`, you can do that in its `equals` method. Now your code will be more maintainable, because you can change this behavior in a single location, and it's the most logical location. Also, it will help you replace some of these verbose `for` loops with simple `contains()` calls. *(Note, if you override equals, you should always override `hashcode` as well. The IDE can help you generate these together.)*

I would also change the parameters for `Album.addSong()` and `removeSong()` to take a `Song` instance instead of making `Album` responsible for instantiating `Song`s.

And a tip. Use `final` when declaring fields that don't need to change, especially collections. This reduces the number of mutable things you have to keep track of. When you have a non-final `List` field, it is mutable in two different ways: you could change the contents of the list or replace the list entirely. Keep it simpler by restricting that to one way of modifying it.

Comment: thanks, have a good day

Comment: do you suggest me to create a Main class object in the main function and call runPlaylist with this object? like this Main play = new Main(); play.runPlaylist();

Comment: Yes. And probably rename the class Playlist.

Comment: so there is no rule that the program must contain the main class? the main class is where psvm method is right?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the name of the class with the `main` method is. Personally, in a case like this, I would have a Playlist class and a separate Main class that has nothing in it except a main method that instantiates your Playlist class and uses it.